# Kotlin Coroutines - Single Producer, Multiple Consumer w/ selective message consumption

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm exploring Kotlin producer-consumer pattern using Kotlin co-routines. In my use case, I've one producer which produces IP packets, and I'm forwarding those using either `DatagramChannel` or `SocketChannel`, depending on whether it was a `UDP` or `TCP` segment respectively. To put it visually, the producer gives me `(IP Header|Transport Header|Payload)`, which is represented by custom data class `IPDatagram` in the below code.

```
fun start() {
    forward(ipPkts())
}

fun ipPkts() = scope.produce<Pair<DatagramType, IPDatagram>> {
    while(isActive) {
        val pkt = readVpnIf0()
        send(Pair(pkt.id, pkt))
    }
}

fun forward(channel: ReceiveChannel<Pair<DatagramType, IPDatagram>>) = scope.launch {
    channel.consumeEach {
        val (type, pkt) = it
        when(type.transportProtocol) {
            UDP -> udpWrite(pkt)
            TCP -> tcpWrite(pkt)
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, but I am using a single `kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel` for both the TCP and UDP write functions, which are kind-of independent in its own right. I referred to the `fan-out` approach provided in [Kotlin Language Guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html), but that doesn't quite fit in my use case to spawn multiple consumers since the UDP and TCP segments would be interleaved.

**Question**: Is there a way to have multiple consumers and *selectively pick up messages* from the same `Channel`, provided the channel has some `capacity` to it. In others words, the TCP consumer will move on to process the 2nd packet without waiting for the 1st one if it is a UDP segment, and vice versa. Sample queued pkts: `UDP | TCP | TCP | UDP`.

Currently, I've used two separate `Channel`s for TCP and UDP, but I feel that it is a bit of an ugly solution. Looking forward to learn something new :)

Comment: You can use the experimental `consumeAsFlow` and then create two different ones by using `filter`, like `filter { type.transportProtocol == UDP }` to get one flow each. I hope it fits your needs.

Comment: @Neo Good to know something new. Let me have a look at it!